# Length of a curve in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \Delta \to \Bbb{C}$ be an injective holomorphic function, where $\Delta$ is the open unit disc in the complex plane.

Let $g: \Delta \to \Bbb{C}$ be holomorphic such that $g^2 = f'$

For a real number $s\in(0,1)$ let the curve $\gamma_s : (0,2\pi) \to \Bbb{C}$ be give by

$$\gamma_s(t) = f(se^{it})$$

Let $L(s)$ be the length of $\gamma_s$. Write $L(s)$ in terms of $s$ and the coefficients {$a_n$} of the Taylor expansion:

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty a_n z^n.$$

So far I've used the definition of length of a curve to get

$$L(s) = \int_0^{2\pi}|\gamma_s'(t)|dt = \int_0^{2\pi}|f'(se^{it})|dt = \int_0^{2\pi}(g(se^{it}))^2dt$$

And then I guess I could replace $g$ for it's Taylor expansion, but I have the feeling I did something very wrong before, anyone kind enough to point it out?

Comment: The basic idea is good, but your expression for $\gamma_s'$ is a little off.

Comment: I tried to see how, but I couldn't find exactly why, any hints?

Comment: You're missing an "inner derivative"

Comment: Ohh, $\gamma_s'(t) = sie^{it}f'(se^{it})$?